# Calling a Javascript function when Required field validator is true

Tags: asp.net

I would like to have a Javascript function to be called when ever my required field validator control is true (i.e when the validator control is fired / error message shown).

Kindly let me know how this can be done.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're validating a TextBox control, the following snippet should do what you want:

```
<asp:TextBox id=txtZip runat=server OnChange="txtZipOnChange();" />
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator id="valZip" runat="server"
   ControlToValidate="txtZip" ...>

<script>
function txtZipOnChange() {
   // get the validator and check if it is valid
   var val = <%= valZip.ClientID %>;
   if (val.isvalid == false) {
     // do something
   }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 8):

You can call a JS function on OnClientlick of the button.

for ex.

```
function CheckValidation() 
    {
        if (Page_ClientValidate())
            {
               // Call Your custom JS function and return value.
            }
    }
```

// Calling JS function

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" 
OnClientClick="return CheckValidation();" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [CustomValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.aspx) control. Set the [CustomValidator.ClientValidationFunction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.clientvalidationfunction.aspx) property to the *javascript* function and the [CustomValidator.ValidateEmptyText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.validateemptytext.aspx) property to *false*.